# Chain DAO methods in Spring/Hibernate for Lazy initializations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dao, lazy-initialization

I have some model classes with relations to each other (`User`, `Group`, `Message`, etc). For many reasons (I'm not giving the details, but this is not a flexible decision) the relations are **Lazy**, and I want them to remain Lazy.

Sometimes I want to load some class collections. P.e. `user.getGroups()` or `user.getMessages()` but, because of the Lazy load, I need to call `Hibernate.initialize()` in the method of the DAO class, which is OK for me.

The question is, **Is there a strategy to avoid declaring many DAO methods to load several combination of collections, reusing the methods?**

Here is an example of **what I want to avoid**:

*UserController*:

```
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/view/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String view(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        // Choose one between the following, depending on the case
        User user = userService.getUser(id);
        User user = userService.getUserWithGroups(id);
        User user = userService.getUserWithGroupsAndMessages(id);
        //...
    }
}
```

And the *UserDAOImpl*:

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
    @Override
    public User getUser(long id) {
        return (User) this.getCurrentSession().get(User.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserWithGroups(long id) {
        User user = (User) this.getCurrentSession().get(User.class, id);
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getGroups());
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserWithGroupsAndMessages(long id) {
        User user = (User) this.getCurrentSession().get(User.class, id);
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getGroups());
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getMessages());
        return user;
    }
}
```

The point is **I want to avoid creating multiple DAO methods for each combination of collections that must be loaded for each case**. I'd like to achieve a call syntaxis in the Controller similar to `User user = userService.getUser(id).initGroups().initMessages();`, to chain only the specific methods I need in every case.

But in this particular example, the `initXXX()` methods would be in the model class `User`, which may not contain any `@Autowired service`, and because of that is not a possible solution.

Any ideas?

**--EDIT--**

Some non-working ideas:

**Option 1.** Declare `initGroups()` in `User` model class:

*User*

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    //...

    public User initGroups() {
        Hibernate.initialize(getGroups());
        return this;
    }
}
```

Called from Controller this way: `User user = userService.getUser(id).initGroups();`

**Option 2.** Declare `initGroups()` in `UserService` and `UserDAO`:

**UserServiceImpl**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    //...

    @Override
    public User initGrupos(User user) {
        return userDAO.initGroups(user);
    }
}
```

**UserDAOImpl**

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    //...

    @Override
    public User initGroups(User user) {
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getGroups());
        return user;
    }
}
```

Called from Controller this way:

```
User user = userService.getUser(id);
user = userService.initGroups(user);
```

**Result** (both the same):

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:484)
    org.hibernate.Hibernate.initialize(Hibernate.java:78)
    ...
```

Comment: Why would you need the service? For example, `initGroups()` method shall only contain `Hibernate.initialize(getGroups())`, am I wrong?

Comment: If I implement `initGroups()` in the `User` model class with that piece of code, I got an exception because is out of the session: `org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session`

Comment: Hmm. As far as I understand Hibernate (and JPA), You do not have to call `Hibernate.initialize()`. You just have to be sure that Your object is in managed state. If it is in managed state `user.getGroups()` will initialize groups list automatically.

Comment: As far as I know, if you have Lazy collections (which is my case) you need to initializate while you are still in the session. If you don't do that and you try to access them later (in a JSP, for example) it will throw a `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`

Comment: The logic you have in your controller should be in a service method, the service method should be `@Transactional` and then the inits will work. The problem is you are executing code outside of a transaction and thus active session. Although it isn't weird to have multiple specific methods for certain use cases imho. You can optimize those methods/queries for specific usecases.

Comment: The Service classes are `@Transactional` (you can see it in the bottom examples). If the `initXxx()` methods must be called inside the Service methods, therefore I think the Service method must be a specific one (like `getUserWithGroupsAndMessages()`) to return a user object with its properly initializated collections to the Controller. So... it appears to be no other option but making specific methods to retrieve and load, all-in-one.

Answer (score 2):

The init methods don't need the service, they just need to call Hibernate.initialize while maintaining the previous Hibernate session which loaded the object in the first place (that is the most important part).

Comment: Can you extend your answer with an example? I'm not a Spring/Hibernate pro, so I don't see very clear what you mean.

Comment: You don't have any code where you show how you handle the transactions, but in your example you would have to make sure, that you start your transaction before you execute 'User user = userService.getUser(id).initGroups().initMessages();', and after that, close the transaction/session. Then it is enough to call just Hibernate.initialize(...) in the initXXX methods.

Comment: The code in the `UserDAOImpl` is an example of my real working code (modified to post in the question). The `XxxDAOImpl` classes extends from an `AbstractDAO` which has an `@Autowired SessionFactory`, and that's all. I call the `XxxDAOImpl` through the corresponding `XxxService`.

Comment: I think I understood what you mean in your answer. But I've already commented: The Session is `@Autowired` inside the `XxxDAOImpl` classes. But, if I retrieve an `user` object (receiving it in the Controller) and then make another call to the DAO passing the `user` object, an Exception raises telling me that the Session is not bound with that object. For further info, take another look to my question, I've edited to add a couple of examples.

Comment: @DaniSancas what dunni is telling you is that you should not initialize the groups from the controller. That is too late because the transaction has already been commited and the session is closed. This initialization must be done in the service layer, while the transaction is not committed yet and the session is not closed. Or you can use an OpenSessionInView interceptor or filter, that will leave the session open even after the transaction has committed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jb-nizet. So you suggest me to create in the DAO/Service (where the session is) some methods like `getUser()`, `getUserWithGroups()`, `getUserWithMessages()`, `getUserWithGroupsAndMessages()`, etc? On the other hand, I've tested a method using **reflection**. For example: `getUser(long id, String[] initMethods)`, where `initMethods` is an array with `getGroups`, `getMessages`, etc. Then, using reflection, I call `Hibernate.initialize()` on those methods passed by args. Sounds like a good or bad idea?

Comment: Horrible idea. Now if you refactor your code and rename a method, you'll have an invalid method name. You could pass an instance of UserInitializer instead, where UserInitializer would be an interface that defines a callback method `void initializeUser(User u)`. It would be up to the implementation (written as an anonymous class or lambda, for example) to initialize the user the way it wants to.

Comment: Talking about reflection, you're right, sounds like a bad idea. Talking about a `UserInitializer interface` I don't know how could it help (I've poor Java knowledge, and dunno about anonymous/lambda classes). The point to achieve is that sometimes I'll need the user without collections, sometimes with groups, or messages, or both... And I want a *shortcut* to get those different combinations without declaring and implementing ALL the possible combinations in the DAO/Service classes.